# rails assets path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, assets

I have in

```
  <link href="/assets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but when I go to `http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css`

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.css"
```

P.S. Rails 3.1.0.rc4, ruby 1.8.7

Comment: is the assets folder under your public folder?

Comment: Im having the same issue. The assets folder automatically installs to app/assets, so that's where it belongs... you'd assume that the default stylesheet tag ( <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %> ) points to the public folder.. but for whatever reason it points to the assets folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems Sprockets / Rails 3.1 were acting up for me w/ ruby 1.9.2-p180 ... updating to Ruby-1.9.2-p290 seemed to stop the issue.

Maybe not related to your issue... but useful for anyone else having that issue using those versions of Rails & Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

I found that I had something similar going on after updating to Rails 3.1 this evening.  I was working on a project that didn't use ActiveRecord, so I had a modified my `application.rb` to exclude it.  The line that usually reads `require 'rails/all'` to only include the parts I needed, like this:

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

This list has changed in Rails 3.1 to include Sprockets, the core component to making the asset pipeline work.  I got the asset pipeline serving the serving content as expected by adding this line to the bottom of the list:

```
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

After restarting, `/assets/application.js` and other assets began working as expected.

Note: if you have a custom setup like this, be sure to open the `railties` gem and look at the contents of `lib/rails/all.rb` which may have changed (as in this case).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your answer! Adding `require "sprockets/railtie"` solved my problem too.

Answer (score 1):

Your scripts and styles will be loaded from the public folder. Drop the assets folder under public and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have no folder assets in public

Comment: I know. I'm suggesting that you move your assets folder from your_project/app to your_project/public.

Comment: This shouldn't have to be done. Rails 3.1 stores all assets in `app/assets` now.

Comment: I agree. it shouldnt have to be moved.

Answer (score 1):

In the application layout file, if you have

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/assets/application" %>
```

which gives

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.css"
```

TRY changing it to

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: This is not the answer. every application file contains <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>. so no need to replace any thing.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following line in application.rb:

```
    config.assets.enabled = true
```

in bottom of class Application < Rails::Application